# Detecting a click on a dynamic drop-down-box with extension javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to detect a click on a list element in Javascript - but there's a twist. The list element is in a drop-down from a search bar in Quora. [www.quora.com](http://www.quora.com) - Specifically, I want to detect when a user clicks the add question button and brings up the popup box.

[image]

The popup box consists of some extra divs that were either hidden or generated dynamically. The html for the lists looks like

```
<li class="addquestionitem" id="__w2_FWrLuSU_list_item_11">
```

When I mouse over that particular list element, it changes to

```
<li class="addquestionitem selected" id="__w2_FWrLuSU_list_item_11">
```

Right now, I have code that looks like:

```
$("li[class='addquestionitem selected']").click(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('this link has been clicked');
        $("div[id$=_publish_checkboxes]").append(element);
    }
```

but even the alert is not showing up. Any suggestions?

**Update**
None of the posted solutions below seemed to work. I also tested with the create board button on the quora homepage, which when clicked produces a similar css-embedded popup. It worked there. Specifically, the selector I used was:

```
$("a[class='add_content_link action_button icon_action_button']")
```

Don't really see why it wouldn't work on the comparable case with the add question button

**Update 2**
Here's the manifest file. :

```
{
    "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://www.quora.com/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "page": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.quora.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "read_in_array.js", "add.js", "popup.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that build the drow-down? It is likely that it triggers a custom event on selection of items, which you should use.

Comment: How did you apply that code where it worked, via commandline? Or are you writing a userscript?

Comment: this is for a google chrome exension

Comment: Please show your manifest file. I believe that you're either not loading jQuery, or you're not setting the correct `matches` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

You will need to wrap the $.ready function around everything else. Also, as the drop-down is likely to be built dynamic, I suggest to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Next, your class selector looks curious, and I think you could also simply omit the `selected` class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "li.addquestionitem", function() {
        alert('this link has been clicked');
        $("div[id$=_publish_checkboxes]").append(element);
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated my question because I'm still having some trouble. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hm, the dropdown code may be faulty and stop the click event from bubbling, causing delegated events to fail. Could you show us that code, maybe on a demo page somewhere?`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the `.click()` event listener doesn't have anything to fire, because it's waiting for `$(document).ready()`, which has already happened before the click.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li[class='addquestionitem selected']").click(function() {
        alert('this link has been clicked');
        $("div[id$=_publish_checkboxes]").append(element);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.click()` is an event listener, listening for a click event on an element and running a function. If the function it runs has `$(document).read(function(){ //do stuff });`, `document.ready` is a condition that must be met before anything will run, but the problem is that `document.ready` is not only a condition, it's also an event that only happens when the document finishes loading. So the click listener is waiting for an event that's already occurred.

Comment: No. `$().ready` is like a condition (correct: it is a Deferred), once it is fulfilled all functions will be executed. The problem is rather that the selector would have matched no elements, because it was executed before the DOM was ready.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an event that needs to be delegated either to the document or the parent container. Your click function is getting bound right away, and if the li doesn't have the class of selected, it won't get bound. So, to listen to clicks via the parent, do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#__w2_FWrLuSU_results_list").on("click", "li.addquestionitem", function()
    {
        alert('this link has been clicked');
        $("div[id$=_publish_checkboxes]").append(element);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addquestionitem').live('click', function(){
        alert('this link has been clicked');
        $("div[id$=_publish_checkboxes]").append(element);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the event listners for that element (select the element and then look at the right in the Elements panel at Event Listners and look for an event targeting that element and its on the mousedown) you'll notice their not using click, but `mousedown`.  So I guess its happening before yours and maybe their stopping it bubbling, not sure on that but change your event to `mousedown` and it will fire.  Also this element may not be available straight after dom ready (not sure on that one), so you may have to use a setTimeout to keep checking for the element, or mutation observers or something specific for the site.

```
// wait for the element to exist then do your thing
var wait = function() {
    if ($("li.addquestionitem").length > 0) {
        console.debug('found it');
        $('.addquestionitem').live('mousedown', function() {
            alert('this link has been clicked');
            $("div[id$=_publish_checkboxes]").append(element);
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout (waiting, 500);
    }
}
wait();
```